# Why is my ASP.NET Core middleware never called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to write my first middleware, and was looking at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48054013/706346), which references [this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/index?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-3.0).

I tried the simplest middleware I could imagine...

```
public class MyMiddleware {
  private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

  public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) =>
    _next = next;

  public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IConfiguration configuration) {
    // Other code would go here...
    await _next(context);
  }
}
```

...and referenced it at the end of the `Configure` method in `StartUp.cs`...

```
app.UseMiddleware<UserChosenMiddleware>();
```

However, if I put a breakpoint inside the `Invoke` method of my middleware, I see that it never gets called.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: try moving it up in your `ConfigureMethod`

Comment: @DanielA.White Ah, that was the problem. If it was before the call to `app.UseRouting` it worked, but not after. Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: they run from top (outer)  to down (inner). other ones might not call the next delegate.

Comment: @DanielA.White I guess I was fooled by the fact that everything else in there is the stuff added when the project was created. I naively assumed that being out-of-the-box Microsoft code, it would all behave! Silly me :)